# Implementing redelivery policy from consumer side with stomp in ActiveMQ

Tags: ruby, activemq-classic, stomp

How can we implement redelivery policy from consumer side with stomp in ActiveMQ?
Is it even be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look to using the local transaction support in STOMP. This will enable you to commit and rollback messages to provide a redelivery pattern.

A recommended consumer error handling pattern:

If the message is invalid (ie.. bad JSON or XML) move to DLQ immediately. The message will never improve in quality and there is no reason to do repeated retries.

If the 'next step' in processing is down (ie. the database) reject delivery and the implement a delay between your next receive() call and track a retry limit to provide an escape hatch. This also has the benefit of allowing other consumers on the queue to attempt processing the message and eliminates the problem where one consumer has a dead path from holding up a messages.